# Can you operate on XML / HTML documents in node.js?

Tags: dom, node.js

Is it possible to load an XML / HTML document with node.js and perform operations such as getElementsByTagName ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node.js doesn't give you a DOM "out of the box", but there is a great module that provides a proper HTML DOM: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom.

---

Edit: there are also several modules that help with interacting with XML. Here's a list of them on the wiki (this page is deprecated): https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml

Answer (score 3):

[**Cheerio**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio): Tiny, fast, and elegant implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
//=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```

Comment: This is the best answer here if you're wanting to query HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out https://github.com/robtweed/ewdDOM

This is a persistent DOM implementation using the Globals database